# How are Minecraft plugins updated?

Tags: minecraft

Im browsing Bukkit plugins here: https://dev.bukkit.org/

and a lot of the plugins are abandoned and are outdated.

These plugins dont work without the current version of Minecraft released.

So how are these plugins actually updated to use the latest version of Minecraft?

I went to YouTube for some tutorials but **ALL** of them are severely outdated and are vague at best on how its done.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, a plugin is built using a library, that's the same used in the server.

Usually, plugin developers use Bukkit API or a similar one, such as Spigot API to build their plugins.

When the Bukkit Platform gets updated, so does the Library on which plugins are built. Whenever that happens, plugin Developers must rebuild/recompile their plugins for the new version.

When the plugins aren't updated for the new version, they break. Bukkit doesn't always keep version compatibility, and in those case, older versions won't work.

To update the plugins, a developer must import the new library on their source code, and fix any methods that might have changed. He or she should then recompile the plugin and export the jar to be run in a Bukkit Server.

Comment: True. At least they often only deprecate functions, but sometimes, especially as Microsoft overtook Mojang, they removed many of the old functions.